# Removing the user's password from UnboundId LDAP search results

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Using [ApacheDS](https://github.com/apache/directory-server), I can do `DefaultDirectoryService#setPasswordHidden` to ensure that when I make LDAP queries, the records that come back remove the `userPassword` attribute from the result set.

How would I achieve the same using [UnboundId](https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk), say with `InMemoryDirectoryServer`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by creating my own `InMemoryOperationInterceptor`:

```
static class PasswordRemovingOperationInterceptor 
    extends InMemoryOperationInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void processSearchEntry(InMemoryInterceptedSearchEntry entry) {
        if (!entry.getRequest().getAttributeList().contains("userPassword")) {
            if (entry.getSearchEntry().getAttribute("userPassword") != null) {
                Entry old = entry.getSearchEntry();
                Collection<Attribute> attributes = old.getAttributes().stream()
                    .filter(attribute -> 
                        !"userPassword".equals(attribute.getName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                Entry withoutPassword = new Entry(old.getDN(), attributes);
                entry.setSearchEntry(withoutPassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then adding this to the startup configuration:

```
InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig config = ...;
config.addInMemoryOperationInterceptor(new PasswordRemovingOperationInterceptor());
```

Is there a more elegant way, though?